# How to make CORPORATE RATE TYPE the only option to choose in Oracle form?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, erp, oracle-ebs

So, there are four options in Rate Type field (spot, corporate, user and fixed)  on the Invoice Workbench in OEBS.

How do I make corporate rate type the main and default option and hide the remaining three.

Thanks in advance!

The Rate Type field
[image] and
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuihg.png]

Comment: Sounds like you are in an Oracle e-Business Suite environment.  That makes this not a programming question for S.O.  So, before I vote to close, I will just direct you to Oracle Support note 1534116.1 "How to change a LOV query from Forms Personalization".  Good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about personalizing the Oracle e-Business Suite.

Comment: If you don't have an Oracle Support account you could also try asking your question o the Oracle E-Business Suite forum. There's plenty of EBS experts there. [Check it out](https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/oracle-applications/e-business_suite/e-business-suite-technology/general_ebs_discussion)